# Which tool is used for website link checking and spelling checking in manual testing

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing

Currently I am checking a website.

In the website I need to check spelling errors and broken links.

Is there is any software/tool to do this task?

Comment: Is there any tool for android and ios apps to check the spelling inside apps.

Comment: @armate - you're welcome to ask your own question, rather than piggybacking off a two year old one

Answer (score 4):

If you write this same question on Google You will get a long list of tools, applications and browser addons for running a spelling and grammar check and a link test for websites.

Personally, what I do is copy the content of web page and paste it in a Word Processor like MS Word or Libre Office Word and run the spelling and grammar check in it for finding the issues. For Final verification I go through the content to make sure it is correct.

Sometimes the spelling and grammar are correct but the sentence is wrong or is unfit. For this part I don't rely on tools but my knowledge of English.

For link testing there are countless tools of which I prefer the following,

[LinkChecker](https://wummel.github.io/linkchecker/)

[W3C Link Validator](https://validator.w3.org/checklink)

Answer (score 4):

Checking Website for broken links and Spell check is considered an important part of Manual testing teams at software testing company.

Doing it manually would be a nightmare, so today we’re going to look at a few tools to automate these type testing services which can speed things up for a manual testing.

Checking Website for broken links and Spell check on a regular basis is important because nobody likes a broken link. It’s a bad experience for your website visitors.

Below are some tools to validate the spell check and broken links on the website.

**Broken link testing tools:**
1. Check my links(Chrome extension for validating links)
Check My Links is a link checker that crawls through your web page and looks for broken links. 'Check My Links' is an extension developed primarily for web designers, developers and content editors.
When you're editing a web page that has lots of links, wouldn't it be handy to be able to quickly check that all the links on the page are working fine?
That's where 'Check My Links' comes in. 'Check My Links' quickly finds all the links on a web page and checks each one for you.

It highlights which ones are valid and which ones are broken, simple as that.
HTTP response codes and full URLs of broken links are published in the Console log
(Found in: 'Chrome > Tools > Javascript Console' or Ctrl+Shift+J).

The latest version of this extension has optional 'warnings' for empty href attributes, trailing #s and anchor tags. Also, invalid links can now be dumped into the console in CSV format for export.
Sets 'nofollow' default to false on first run & checks for the existence of either ID or Name attributes on pages linked to using URL fragments.
You can optionally check rel="nofollow" links, anchor links are now also validated, GET is now the default request method and you can now close the report box and re-run the checking process multiple times without any weirdness.
You can now optionally cache valid links (green coloured, HTTP 200). This means the extension will always consider them valid each time you run the checking process, and therefore check only the red (broken) links each time.
Using this tool will make web pages checking A LOT faster and easier for broken links. It is one of the best comprehensive tools for validating links on websites.
Other online link checking tools:

1. ScreamingFrog Spider SEO: https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/
2. Xenu Link Sleuth: http://xenus-link-sleuth.en.softonic.com/
3. Google Chrome Page Checking Plugin: Check My Links
4. Online Domain Tools: http://website-link-checker.online-domain-tools.com/
5. SortSite - Error and Link Checking: http://www.powermapper.com/products/sortsite/checks/link-checker/
6. W3C: https://validator.w3.org/checklink
7. Dead Link checker: http://www.deadlinkchecker.com/
8. Online Broken Link Checker: http://www.brokenlinkcheck.com/
9. Dr Link Checker: http://www.drlinkcheck.com/

**Spell Checking**

**Spell Checker (Firefox Add-on):** Checks the (whole) web page (and not the text inside edit box) for spelling mistakes and highlights it.
It checks the Spelling mistakes all over the web page. It uses Firefox's inbuilt dictionary to check the spellings.
There are many sites available which check the spelling mistake on the website but for that, you must have your site live.
But what to do when a site is under construction and you are testing it. To copy whole page text and past into some utility that checks the spelling mistakes is tedious work to do. This add-on will help you in this case.

To check spelling in other languages you will have to download the dictionaries, you can down it from here.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/language-tools/

Note: this add-on works with ASCII character only (mean would work with some languages only)

**Spell Checker (Chrome Extension):**
Spell Checker extension for Chrome. It's easy to use and fast.
This extension supports 12 languages for spell check. It's a tool to check spellings of words and come up with suggestions for misspelt words.
* User defined shortcuts, colour
* User dictionary support
* Chrome context menu support

Other Spell link checking tools:

1. respel: http://respelt.com/
2. Ninjas: http://www.internetmarketingninjas.com/online-spell-checker.php
3. JsSpell: https://www.jspell.com/public-spell-checker.html
4. Checkdog: http://checkdog.com/
5. SEO Chat:http://tools.seochat.com/tools/free-spell-checker/
6. typosaur: http://typosaur.us/
7. SortSite - Website Spell Checking: http://www.powermapper.com/products/sortsite/checks/website-spell-checker/
8. spellcheckplus: http://spellcheckplus.com/
9. W3C: https://www.w3.org/2002/01/spellchecker

**Which tool is best for you?**

Choosing the right tool will depend on your needs.
Consider these things below :

•    How complex is your website?: 
Large websites will take longer to scan, and a desktop app may not be up to the challenge.

•    What are you trying to accomplish?:

Are you just looking for broken links, or are you trying to make your website more usable?

•    How frequently are you running scans? 
Is this a recurring task or a one-time audit?

Keeping these things in mind will help you select the right tool to validate the Spell check and broken links for websites.

Answer (score 0):

You can check links by regex, spelling thru dictionary - but spelling checking is better made by person - there will be always something, which will not pass...